# Изменение имени dll с исходного Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll на my.dll делает её неработоспособной

Tags: .net, dll

Для работы с Планировщиком заданий Windows я использую библиотеку Task Scheduler (устанавливаю через Nuget Package Manager: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=taskscheduler).

Если установить nuget пакет, выполнить сборку проекта, в папке с исполняемым файлом появится файл Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll, на который есть ссылка в проекте. Если библиотеку (файл dll) вынуть из проекта, удалить пакет, положить на место и сделать ссылку на неё - всё будет работать так же нормально. Ничего нового.

Но вот стоит поменять имя файла библиотеки, снова сделать ссылку, удалив прежнюю, это дело работать уже не будет. Т.е. изменение имени dll (с исходного "Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll" на, например, "my.dll") делает её неработоспособной... В чём проблема?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, CLR устроена так, что в общем случае нельзя просто взять и переименовать сборку. По умолчанию, CLR при поиске сборки ориентируется на ее внутреннее имя (из метаданных), но при этом ищет не по внутреннему имени, а по имени файла, т.е. по строкам типа `[application base] / [assembly name].dll` и т.п. Если нужно, чтобы при поиске сборки использовалось имя файла, нужно использовать параметр codebase в конфигурации:

```
<configuration>
...

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyLibrary"/>
        <codeBase href="my.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

...
</configuration>
```

Если сборка использует строгое имя, нужно будет указать больше параметров:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler" 
              publicKeyToken="c416bc1b32d97233"   culture="neutral"/>
        <codeBase href="my.dll" version="2.8.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Документация: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

Comment: Классно, не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: @D.Stark Возможно, в вашем случае требуется указать строгое имя сборки вида "AssName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=..., PublicKeyToken=...". Используйте утилиту Fuslogvw.exe из статьи по ссылке для отладки загрузки сборок.

Comment: Это я пробовал. Может скинуть проект?

Comment: @D.Stark Проверил, у меня работает по второму варианту с  TaskSheduler (с самописной библиотекой без цифровой подписи работает и по первому варианту). Какая именно у вас ошибка выводится?

Comment: FileNotFoundException

Comment: @D.Stark Может, проблема на самом деле в чем-то другом. Изучайте логи Fuslogvw.exe, смотрите что именно CLR не может найти. Ваш проект я вряд ли смогу открыть сейчас, у меня ничего новее VS2010 под рукой нету. В целом схема точно рабочая, вам лишь нужно сделать все правильно.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7BQL6K07

Comment: app.config https://pastebin.com/GA95sxA8

Comment: @D.Stark имена атрибутов должны начинаться с маленькой буквы: publicKeyToken, а не PublicKeyToken

Comment: Хах. Это помогло

Comment: Странно. Как только я перемещаю библиотеку в другую папку вместе с EXE, всё перестаёт работать. Как указать что искать нужно прямо в текущей папке? В списке References в свойствах ссылки указан полный путь к DLL, а должно быть наверное только имя.

Comment: @D.Stark параметр codebase (при использовании относительного пути) и так указывает искать в текущей папке. Что отображается в References - при его наличии не важно. Скорее всего, проблема в чем-то другом, например вы переименовали exe, но забыли переименовать конфиг. Если неочевидно, так же смотрите логи Fuslogvw, что и откуда CLR пытается грузить и на чем падает.

Comment: Нужно чтобы файл config тоже был в текущей папке... Т.е. за собой придётся таскать и dll и config. Я думал файл конфигурации включается в состав модуля. Неудобно.

Comment: @D.Stark  Если нужно то же самое реализовать кoдoм, я думаю это возможно: см.  [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Хотя не знаю, насколько это будет удобнее.