# Почему не работает Assembly.Load?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, .net-5

Пытаюсь динамически подключить библиотеку dll. Использую Assembly:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Assembly a = Assembly.Load("file");
        }
```

Вылазит ошибка "Не удалось найти указанный файл", имя файла совпадает с тем что пытаюсь открыть.

Если использую LoadFrom, то вылазит это:

System.BadImageFormatException: "Could not load file or assembly 'file, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)"

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET 5? Вы буквально передаете строку "file", или там все же есть расширение .dll?

Comment: NET 5, передаю так как написал, без расширения, но с ним тоже не работает

Comment: А если передать полный путь к dll? Буквально Assembly a = Assembly.Load(@"c:\Tmp\MyAssembly.dll"); ?

Comment: пробовал передавать через Environment.CurrentDirectory + "file.dll"

Comment: А, ну да, Assembly.Load принимает имя сборки, поэтому расширения там быть и не должно. Ваша первая проблема описана здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155963/ А вот вторая проблема означает, что вы пытаетесь загрузить [ссылочную сборку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies), вы точно не ошиблись файлом? Что это за сборка "file", вы ее сами компилировали, или взяли откуда-то?

Comment: Я заменил название, чтоб не путать, но зборку я действительно написал сам, в ней нет ничего кроме двух функций которые ничего не делают, сделал исключительно чтоб проверить динамическую загрузку.

Comment: Менять имя сборки не рекомендуется, это может привести к ошибкам при разрешении зависимостей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818686/ Но странно, что ошибка упоминает "Reference assemblies" - этого не должно быть для обычной сборки....

Comment: я его изменил когда писал вопрос, а так она называется так как я ее и скомпилировал

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, первая ссылка помогла, теперь вылазит исключительно вторая ошибка, но я немного не понял как ее исправить, как можно сделать сборку не ссылочной?

Comment: А вы не устанавливаете какие-либо нестандартные свойства проекта, например ProduceReferenceAssembly? При обычной статической загрузке сборка работает? Реальное имя сборки случайно не совпадает с системными библиотеками?

Comment: Я понял в чем была ошибка, после компиляции я для использования брал dll из папки ref, а нужно было взять файл на каталог выше, то-есть из папки Release\net5.0-windows. После замены файла все заработало. Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что в файле конфигурации не была включена функция подгрузки библиотек из локального каталога. Это описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155963/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83).

Также я брал ссылочную сборку, находиться она в каталоге ref по пути: Release\net5.0-windows\ref\ваша_скомпилированная_dll.dll, но необходимо брать библиотеку из каталога Release\net5.0-windows\ваша_скомпилированная_dll.dll